# comparing left join and outer apply doing the same thing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, join, trigger

I have an update trigger on a table that that insert rows in another database/table

the query look like

```
insert into otherdb.table
select manyfield
from inserted
  left join (select id, 
                    timestamp, 
                    row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) as rownum
             from sometable) as t1
      on inserted.id = t1.id and
         rownum = 1
```

**sometable** have over 7 millions rows and have proper indexing

while doing execution plan i can see that if there is 1 updated row, that [windowing fuction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) (proper name used?) retrieve the whole table do to the rows numbering and get executed once, it is using **index scan**

same(it will retrieve once the 7 millions rows) if inserted have 20 rows or inserted have 50,000 rows

now the usage of that trigger is mostly 1 row update (we do have some odd case where it will be 20-100 rows and even thousands)

I refactored this query to look like

```
insert into otherdb.table
select manyfield
from inserted
  outer apply join (select top 1 id, 
                    timestamp
                    from sometable
                    where inserted.id = sometable.id
                    order by timestamp desc) as t1
```

same result at the end but the execution plan change.

now it is using **index seek** and it will return 1 row per inserted row

when i do a huge update of 50,000 rows, the execution plan will tell me **number of execution 50,000** instead of one when doing the left join version.

to resume everything;

left join: 1 big operation being reused by all inserted row

outer apply: 1 small operation being executed once per inserted row

my question is, at this point i don't know enough about execution plan to decide which kind of join i should keep, **left join** or **outer apply**?

this is being used by 500-1000 users at the same time and we have timeout error maybe related to this trigger, we currently use the left join query

**EDIT**

result of some actual execution plan, **select on 55017 rows**

left join:

**estimated subtree cost:** ~78
**memory grant:** ~156k
**estimated number of rows:** ~57k

outer apply:

**estimated subtree cost:** ~99
**memory grant:** ~163k
**estimated number of rows:** ~55k

hybrid(solution of Paparazzi but using innner join, for left join see above):

**estimated subtree cost:** ~87
**memory grant:** ~170k
**estimated number of rows:** ~56k

---

result of some actual execution plan, **update on 55017 rows (trigger)**

left join:

**estimated subtree cost:** ~401
**memory grant:** ~455k
**estimated number of rows:** ~225k

outer apply:

**estimated subtree cost:** ~136
**memory grant:** ~153k
**estimated number of rows:** ~52k

hybrid(solution of Paparazzi but using innner join, for left join see above):

**estimated subtree cost:** ~126
**memory grant:** ~156k
**estimated number of rows:** ~53k

Comment: Perhaps this post from Paul White in 2014 will be helpful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75048/outer-apply-vs-left-join-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - you might get the best of both

```
select manyfield 
from  ( select manyfield
             , row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t1.timestamp desc) as rownum 
          from inserted 
          left join sometable t1 
                 on inserted.id = t1.id
      ) tt
where rownum = 1 or t1.id is null
```

Comment: so far i like your, +1 and going to give the green check i think before the end of the day

Comment: oops when i did my test i was using inner join on sometable instead of left join while using your solution, left join doesn't change the result from the actual code

Comment: But that depends on the data. Yes a left and regular join *can* return the same data but they are still not the same.